# Как в android вызвать метод из стороннего приложения?

Tags: android-sdk

SmartTV TCL, пробую регулировать яркость подсветки из своего приложения, метод

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,50);
```

не подходит, тк в данной модели телевизора траблы с запросом разрешений ***ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS*** , ошибка
*No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.action.MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS }*

Ближе к делу: используя дебаг-консоль в студии нашел что при изменении яркости с пульта вызывается

```
com.tcl.settings.viewmodel.picture.BacklightSeekbarLayoutVM
```

и в консоли вижу

> set: index = 61

Как мне из своего приложения ( или из adb ) вызвать эту функцию или метод, со своими параметрами?